# How to implement the MSG_DONTWAIT on a recv call

Tags: c

I am implementing a server simulation program and want to check if anything was received via a recv from a TCP/IP socket witout waiting. When I place the MSG_DONTWAIT flag, recv returns a length of -1 and errno of "Resource temproarily anavialable". the call works when the MSG_WAITALL flag is used.

Comment: Please read http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions. And I believe this question doesnt belong here

Comment: @thefourtheye Development questions are allowed here see [this question on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6554/107450).  Though you may get a better response from a programming site such as: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 5):

This is not an error but an expected behavior. The documentation of MSG_DONTWAIT states:

*If no data is available, then instead of blocking, return immediately with the error EAGAIN.*

Which means that you should wait for and handle such situation.

Check [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) for the reference and [here](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=6284) for a similar discussion.